# Error when clicking ellipses in Sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Good day to you all - hope somebody can help.

Our Sharepoint 2013 farm supports multiple web applications, but one of them is exhibiting some odd behaviour.

When clicking on the ellipses (or 3 dots, whichever you prefer) next to a document or folder anywhere up or down the structure we get the message, "**ReferenceError: 'filePreviewManager' is undefined**."

Doesn't happen on any other web application in the farm.

Any suggestions as to what this might be, or what configuration settings might be different between web apps to create this error, would be very much appreciated.

Chris.

Comment: Review the ULS logs for more meaningful errors.

Comment: We reviewed them, even used developer mode to try to track any correlation IDs, but no errors are actually generated.

Comment: Review errors on the page load. As this is js it will not show error in ULS if it doesn't contact SP and I think this is the case. But do an IIS reset and review errors on the page load.

Answer (score 1):

I googled "filePreviewManager" and it seems to be an object used to preview documents. Obviously this object is called when it has no value. I don't know where it is declared, but my guess is that your web app cannot find some of the JavaScript files. I would look for files like filepreview.js, preview.js and compare different web apps, i.e. working web apps with not working to see if there are any differences. Best of luck!

Comment: It was a javascript issue, but in the INPLVIEW,js script.

Answer (score 1):

By way of an update - we went to Microsoft support with this and apparently it's a known bug that they're currently investigating.

In the meantime, the workaround can be found here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1c38e04c-ffc7-462e-a3ed-b6c23ccdfca7/sharepoint-2013-getting-an-error-while-clicking-on-the-ellipsis-of-a-document-in-a-document

However, depending on when you last applied a CU, the code changes slightly.